# actionscript3: how to smooth a bitmap?

Tags: actionscript-3

i know about `smoothing = true` but are there any other ways to smooth a bitmap?

Answer (score 1):

you can use [ConvolutionFilter](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filters/ConvolutionFilter.html) to make every pixel's color more fit the neighbours
**upd:** [here's the example](http://sonnati.wordpress.com/2010/10/06/flash-h-264-h-264-squared-%E2%80%93-part-iii/)